# JComponent repaint() in frame from another class

Tags: java, swing, oop, reference

I am working for fun developing and old 80's draw 80 poker game.

```
class DDHGamePanel extends JPanel{
...etc...   
DDHAdvertising adv = new DDHAdvertising();
...etc...

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
adv.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled();
adv.setEnabled(true);
adv.repaint();
 }
}
```

This is the main panel of my game. I took out a lot of code to make this fit better. I have a class DDHAdvertising that has a paint Component.

```
public class DDHAdvertising extends JComponent {

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);  
    drawAdvertisingBanner(g,getBanner1(),30,30);
    g.drawString ("Test",40,360);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to at the end of the `paintComponent` in my `JPanel` be able to repaint any class that extends `JComponent` with the `repaint()` method. I am certain that this can be done but I am not sure how to do it.

I want all of my graphics class that have some component that reference the came, example would be say all of the cards that are draw to the screen. I want a separate class for each component on the screen and then to call its `repaint()` method which should invoke the `paintComponent()` method of that particular class. I have read a lot on the subject but I have not seen this particular example in code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), i don't think people would sent you an email, you should post here, cause stackoverflow serves for future visitors that have same related problem.. so when best effort you put to do the question best go to be the answer.

Comment: what is your problem? are you looking something like a `template method` ?

Comment: *"I want to be able to at the end of the `paintComponent` in my `JPanel` be able to repaint any class that extends `JComponent` with the `repaint()` method."*  Why?  if you mean components contained within `DDHAdvertising` - they are accounted for with `super.paintComponent(g);`.  Otherwise, there should be no need to repaint anything else.  Doing so for a container that **displays** that custom component will lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh, and +1 to @nachokk for suggesting an SSCCE.  That would go a large way to answering my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `super.paintComponent(g);` in the`paintComponent` of the JPanel. It causes all of its children to also be repainted. You should never remove this when you override a component (including JPanel).

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     adv.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled();
     adv.setEnabled(true);
     adv.repaint();
 }
```

Comment: *"`super.paintComponent(g);` .. You should never remove this"*  I kept thinking that was an odd comment to make when I was only really reading the 2nd code snippet, which did *not* remove it.  I missed it in the 1st code snippet! +1

Comment: Yeah I am not sure that adv.repaint() is necessary though, if it is added to the JPanel, but wasn't entirely sure what he wanted.

Comment: *"wasn't entirely sure"*  Neither am I - currently as well as before.  ;)

Comment: paintComponent doesn't paint it's children, but I'm nit picking. +1 none the less

Comment: -1 for _changing_ component state in the paint cycle - that's wrong even when done to something else than the component currently painted: when/how/if something is painted is unspecified, so whatever you do may happen or not.

Comment: I know, but answers shouldn't repeat errors - your turn to them from the code _you_ are showing :-)

Comment: I have this in my paintComponent(). If you have a class that extends JComponent you can have a paintComponent() in that class to repaint everything. You then declare an instance of that object outside of itself say in classA(). How can you call the ClassA() paintComponent from another class.   Someone told me like this YourClassName.repaint(). I tried this and it didn't work, it will compile but does not paint. I want to declare all of my graphics in separate classes and then have them repaint only when that Class is changed. Like a image class for a poker game.  PokerGame.repaint(). Doug

Comment: If I have classA()   and classB() has several say drawstring(...etc...); in them. And I only want to update that to the screen once in a while.   I have a paintComponent that does that work in that class.  ClassB.repaint() in my classA() to repaint the components. I know this is confusing but I was trying to keep everything in separate classes. Like images in one class, button in another and then calling their paintComponent() only when I needed to refresh the screen. my email is doughauf@outlook.com if anyone wants to reply that way.

Comment: I tried using the super.paintComponent() but that didn't seem to repaint the component either. Here might be a better example. If I want to create a class that extends JComponent so that I can use that classes paintComponent to do my thing, whatever that might be.

Comment: I advice you open up a new thread with the more specific questions, it is easier to get help that way as it seems to be outside of the scope of this particular question.

Comment: I tried using the super.paintComponent() but that didn't seem to repaint the component either. Here might be a better example. If I want to create a class that extends JComponent so that I can use that classes paintComponent to do my thing, whatever that might be. Then I want to make a variable in a completely separate class myClass tempVariable

Comment: second half of comment above:Do I have to add this variable or component to the JPanel (which i think that I would have to) and then call the   tempVariable.repaint() method which will call the paintComponent() of my class which should invoke the super.paintComponent() inside of the paintComponent().